# Ionic 4 Reactive Forms clear ion radio group selection

Tags: angular7, ionic4

I am trying to clear `ion-radio-group` selection in Ionic 4.

My html:

```
                        <ion-radio-group formContolName="oilPanStatus" (ionSelect)="OilPanStatusChanged($event)">
                            <ion-list-header>
                                <ion-label>Is the oil-pan status good?</ion-label>
                            </ion-list-header>
                            <ion-item lines="none">
                                <ion-label>Yes</ion-label>
                                <ion-radio slot="start" value="true"></ion-radio>
                            </ion-item>
                            <ion-item lines="none">
                                <ion-label>No</ion-label>
                                <ion-radio slot="start" value="false"></ion-radio>
                            </ion-item>
                        </ion-radio-group>
```

This is my attempt to clear in .ts:

```
        this.Form.reset();
        this.Form.controls.oilPanStatus.reset();
```

I see that the `Form` is correctly reset with all values and errors cleared. But in the UI i see old selection is still shown.

How can i clear the previously selected radio buttons.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure if this is the correct way. But the only way i found to get this to work with reactive forms is:

move `formControlName` to individual `ion-radio` elements:

```
     <ion-radio-group (ionSelect)="Selected($event)">
          <ion-list-header>
               <ion-label>Is the oil-pan status good?</ion-label>
          </ion-list-header>
          <ion-item lines="none">
       <ion-label>Yes</ion-label>
       <ion-radio slot="start" value="true" formContolName="radio" [checked]="radio.value==='true'"></ion-radio>
     </ion-item>
     <ion-item lines="none">
         <ion-label>No</ion-label>
        <ion-radio slot="start" value="false" formContolName="radio" [checked]="radio.value==='false'"></ion-radio>
      </ion-item>
    </ion-radio-group>
```

Then add a `[checked]` property, so that when form is reset(`this.Form.reset()`) the value of the `radio` formControl is set to ''. Thus none of the [checked] conditions are suttisfied and the UI is actually reset.

Comment: not working with ionic 5, checked property deprecated.

Answer (score 1):

Solution for IONIC 5:

i) define radio group reference. 
ii) add a click event with radio group.

Working example: 
**Template code**

```
<ion-radio-group formControlName="future_studies" #refRadio
    (click)="resetRadioGroup(refRadio, $event.target.value, form.controls.future_studies)">
    <ion-list-header>
      <ion-label>My studies</ion-label>
    </ion-list-header>
    <div class="radio-group">
      <ion-item>
        <ion-label>Yes</ion-label>
        <ion-radio slot="start" value="yes"></ion-radio>
      </ion-item>
      <ion-item>
        <ion-label>No</ion-label>
        <ion-radio slot="start" value="no"></ion-radio>
      </ion-item>
    </div>
  </ion-radio-group>
```

**click event handler function:**

```
resetRadioGroup(ref, eventVal, control) {
    if (eventVal === ref.value) {
        setTimeout(() => {
            ref.value = null;
            control.reset();
        }, 100);
    }
}
```

It will reset the radio button also the model/formcontrol too. 
Thumbs up!

Comment: have not tested it. the setTimeout part looks hacky